# Search one map value if it is a key of other map

Tags: javascript, search, dictionary, key, key-value

In javascript, I have 2 maps
map1 = {a:1 , b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5};
map2 = {td:a, bd:c, sd:e};

Now I need to search the values of the map2 which is (a,b,e) if it is the key of the map1 and then update the value of map2 with the corresponding value in map1
Example- map2[td] = a and map[a] = 1 then I want to update map2[td] = 1. Can anyone help me finding an algorithm.

Comment: Trivial. What have you tried?

Comment: I am new to operations on multiple maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop

```
var key;
for (key in map2)
    if (map2[key] in map1)
        map2[key] = map1[map2[key]];
```

You may want to consider what happens if properties are inherited though

Comment: You can use `hasOwnProperty()` to check for inherited properties. But its okay since OP is using pretty ordinary objects.

Comment: @bits it's not a _must_, `for (var key in {}) k; // undefined` it depends on the _Object_ - I mention that inherited properties may need to be considered, but yes, `hasOwnProperty` would be the way to check in those cases.

Comment: Yeah, not `must`, I agree and changed my last comment.

Comment: If you're also really worried about inherited properties, you might also want to invoke it through `Object.prototype`, for example `var checkOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.bind(testObj); checkOwn(someKey);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(map2).forEach(function (d, i) {
    map2[d] = map1[map2[d]];
})
```

Comment: This is only supported in ECMAScript 5+

Comment: The one we use here is the spider monkey javascript Engine.

Comment: Well [Spider Monkey supports ECMAScript 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpiderMonkey_(JavaScript_engine)#Standards).

Comment: @cgatian pretty much any browser you care about [is supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_compatibility).